# why i can not use passed refs in input element

Tags: reactjs, reference, null, ref

I am trying to focus on error fields inside of a form and I am using ref to do that but somehow ref always returns null and I am getting errors, I want to use/pass this ref to focus on error field , here error is stored in state which i have not included in code

here is the basic code,

```
class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.textInput = React.createRef();
        this.getErrors = this.getErrors.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        /////
    }

renderSubmitAction() { 

if(errors) {
            
            this.textInput.current.focus();
            
        }

}


render() {
return (
<View key={propertyName}>
                        <FormInput
                            id={id_prefix + propertyName}
                            key={propertyName}
                            ref={this.textInput}
                        />
                    </View>


)

const submitButton = this.renderSubmitAction();

        return (
            <View key={this.state.submitId} style={props.style}>
                {children}
                {props.children}
                {submitButton}
            </View>
        );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

You are running this:

```
this.textInput.current.focus();
```

before this happens:

```
<FormInput
  id={id_prefix + propertyName}
  key={propertyName}
  ref={this.textInput}
/>
```

### Solution

I'm not sure what this is supposed to do:

```
const submitButton = this.renderSubmitAction();
```

But you probably wanted to use this:

```
const submitButton = this.renderSubmitAction;
```

Comment: can not do this as submitButton is used to submit the form ,hence i am trying to run this.textInput.current.focus();  inside renderSubmitAction function

Comment: I don't see any button in your code

Comment: Scroll down you will see this ,

return (
            <View key={this.state.submitId} style={props.style}>
                {children}
                {props.children}
                {submitButton}
            </View>
        );

Comment: Why would you submit the form in every frame instead of doing it on click?

Comment: No Form is a component and it takes input field names as props and has a submit button with it.